# Unable to get the the data from AJAX request to Laravel controller and work with it?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am making the following AJAX call:

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
var token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";

$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "{{route('site.image.store')}}",
      data: {
        imgBase64: dataURL,
      },
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
    }).done(function(response) {
      console.log('done');
});
```

And my controller is:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

However I am getting and empty array `[]`. How can I access the `imgBase64` data and work with it in the controller?

I am not submitting a form to make the post request I am just using the canvas data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it does not work for you is that Laravel uses the `Content-Type` header of the request to determine how to parse the input data.

If you specify `contentType: false` in your request, you're specifically building the AJAX request in such a way that no `Content-Type` header will be sent.

That way Laravel does not know how to parse the body of the request.

So to resolve your issue you have to specify the correct `contentType` for your request. The default for jQuery's `$.ajax()` function is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` (see [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/))